# How to install Netbeans IDE in linuxmint?

Tags: java, netbeans, linux-mint

I am new to Linux.I dont know how to install Netbeans IDE in LInuxmint.
Please write your answers in steps.

Comment: This should help: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps in terminal,first install jdk and then install these things

```
 1)chmod +x ~/Downloads/jdk-8-nb-8-linux-*.sh
 2)cd ~/Downloads && ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to NetBeans website and download install script. Web app will determine what you are running, you need to pick which bundle you want. When you finish download do

```
$ chmod a+x jdk-8uXY-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh
```

and execute it. It will install everything for you. XY is current version of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

//easy method
step 1:go to software manager in linuxmint as you can download many software from there
step 2: go to search bar and type apache netbeans
step 3: click the install and enter your password;